# Where to add remote camunda properties with spring boot?

Tags: spring, camunda

I have Camunda 7.15.0 deployed in GCP Cloud Run. I have an Java 11 application through which I wish to access the Camunda RuntimeService in order to start a process instance, but how do I tell spring about the Camunda service location (GCP URL)?
Is this possible or should I just use rest API and make rest call to camunda/engine-rest?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to talk to a camunda engine on a different machine, you will definitely have to use the REST interface.

You can however wrap the REST client in a runtimeService interface by using the rest-spring-boot [community extension](https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-platform-7-rest-client-spring-boot).

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCamundaRestClient
public class CamundaRestClientExampleApplication {}

@Component
public class ProcessClient {
  private final RuntimeService runtimeService;
  private final RepositoryService repositoryService;
  private final Map<String, String> instances = new ConcurrentHashMap();

  public ProcessClient(
    @Qualifier("remote") RuntimeService runtimeService,
    @Qualifier("remote") RepositoryService repositoryService
  ) {
    this.runtimeService = runtimeService;
    this.repositoryService = repositoryService;
  }


  public void startProcess() {
    VariableMap variables = createVariables()
      .putValueTyped("ID", stringValue("MESSAGING-" + UUID.randomUUID()));
    return runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(
      KEY, 
      businessKey, 
      variables);
  }
}
```

By doing so, you write code as if you where running inside the engine, but requests are directed to the remote engine.